# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}$ using the Squeeze Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}$$

I know that the standard way would be to use the Closed Form of$$1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3$$ However I've been trying to practise using the Squeeze Theorem and thus tried to solve it using the Squeeze Theorem. However, I seem to have made a mistake as I don't get the expected answer.
$$$$My approach:$$$$
Taking $$f(n)=\dfrac{1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}$$ I identified the general term of $f(n)$ as $\dfrac{k^3}{(n^2+1)^2}$ where $1\le k\le n$
$$$$
Clearly $$\dfrac{1^3}{(n^2+1)^2}\le \dfrac{k^3}{(n^2+1)^2}\le \dfrac{n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}$$

Thus $$\dfrac{1^3}{(n^2+1)^2}+\dfrac{1^3}{(n^2+1)^2}+... \text{n times}\le f(n)\le \dfrac{n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}+\dfrac{n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}+... \text{n times}$$

$$\dfrac{n}{(n^2+1)^2}\le f(n)\le \dfrac{n\times n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}$$

$$\dfrac{n}{(n^2+1)^2}\le f(n)\le \dfrac{n^4}{(n^2+1)^2}$$

$$$$However on taking the limits as $n\to \infty$, I'm not getting the correct answer.
$$$$Could somebody please show me where I've gone wrong? Thanks!

Comment: But the answer given (and what I got using the closed form) is $\frac 14$.

Comment: @JimmyR. No the limit is $1/4$.

Comment: Yes, right (I forgot the constant term $1/2$ squared).

Comment: @JimmyR.Could you please specify the constant term you are getting? From what I can see $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n^4}{(n^2+1)^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n^4}{n^4+2n^2+1}$$

Comment: @JimmyR. Could you please show me the constant term you mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: If you use the closed form: $$1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3=(1+2+\dots+n)^2=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2=\frac{(n^4+n^2)}{4}$$

Comment: @JimmyR. Could you please show me what is wrong with my approach? Why does my upper bound not give the correct limit?

Comment: Actually both bounds are too loose (not only the lower one as I wrongly suggested before). The upper bound gives $1$ and the lower gives $0$. So, indeed $0\le 1/4 \le 1$ (which shows that your work is not wrong) but you need tighter bounds. Perhaps squeeze theorem is not easy to apply here.

Comment: @JimmyR. Thanks. Could you suggest how I should tighten my Upper Bound?

Comment: No, I have no idea. But you got some answers that work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$(r + 1)^{4} - r^{4} = 4r^{3} + 6r^{2} + 6r + 1 > 4r^{3}\tag{1}$$ and $$r^{4} - (r - 1)^{4} = 4r^{3} - 6r^{2} + 6r - 1 < 4r^{3}\tag{2}$$ and putting $r = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ and adding these equations we get $$\frac{n^{4}}{4} < S = \sum_{r = 1}^{n}r^{3} < \frac{(n + 1)^{4} - 1}{4}\tag{3}$$ and then we can see that squeeze theorem can be easily applied to get desired limit as $1/4$.

---

**Update**: OP is aware of the exact formula for sum $$S = \sum_{r = 1}^{n}r^{3}$$ and hence he knows that the limit is $1/4$. Since we are supposed to use the Squeeze theorem we must be able to bound the sum $S$ with two functions $f(n), g(n)$ such that $$f(n) < S < g(n)$$ and $$\frac{f(n)}{(n^{2} + 1)^{2}} \to \frac{1}{4}$$ and $$\frac{g(n)}{(n^{2} + 1)^{2}} \to \frac{1}{4}$$ Thus we want the bounds $f(n), g(n)$ to be of type $n^{4}/4$. In your approach the bounds are either too high or too low. Thus the upper bound $g(n)$ for $S$ in your answer looks like $n^{4}$ and lower bound $f(n)$ for $S$ looks like $n$. So from this you can only conclude that desired limit lies between $0$ and $1$.

Now the procedure to get the bounds comes from the technique used to obtain the closed form for $S$. This is done by calculating the differences $$(r + 1)^{4} - r^{4}$$ and $$r^{4} - (r - 1)^{4}$$ Any of the relations $(1)$ or $(2)$ of my answer can be used to derive an exact closed form for $S$, but we only need an approximation so the identities in $(1), (2)$ are given the shape of inequalities by neglecting terms containing $r^{2}, r$ and constant term. By summing these inequalities for $r = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ I don't get an exact formula for $S$ but rather very close bounds for $S$ and that's what we need here.

Comment: You're more or less re-doing a proof for the closed form…

Comment: @Bernard: I am using the technique of getting closed form, but by neglecting the terms like $r^{2}, r,$ etc I am only trying to get bounds for the sum and not the exact closed form. And this is what we need here.

Comment: @Bernard Sir could you please tell me what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: @Bernard: BTW I don't see any other simple technique to get the bounds involving $n^{4}/4$ term.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I couldn't understand your solution. Could you please explain the motivation behind the steps you took and elaborate your solution? Thanks!

Comment: @user342209: I will provide reply in my updated answer. Please wait for few minutes.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thaks Sir. Could you also please explain what is wrong with my Upper Bound?

Comment: @Paramand Singh: I don't see either. You're not in question: the point is I just don't see the interest of this exercise: not using the closed form to redo part of its proof is not particularly fruitful, at least in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard: If it was upto me I would not set this as an exercise. Agree with your point fully.

Comment: @Bernard: Maybe the exercise makes more sense when we replace the power $3$ in numerator by a general integer $k > 0$ and say denominator is $n^{k + 1}$ and ask to prove that it tends to $1/(k + 1)$. I think some would say that such a limit is better evaluated by thinking as limit of Riemann sum and using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to solve the integral. But some might prefer to calculate $(n + 1)^{k} - n^{k}$ and get the bounds as I have done for $k = 3$.

Comment: @Paramand Singh: In a more general context, I fully agree with you.

Answer (score 4):

It is an overkill, but the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) instantly solves the problem.

$f(x)=x^3$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence:
$$\frac{1}{4}=\int_{0}^{1}x^3\,dx \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^3 \tag{1} $$
as well as:
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^3 \leq \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\int_{0}^{1+\frac{1}{n}}x^3\,dx = \frac{1}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3\tag{2} $$
where the difference between the LHS of $(2)$ and the RHS of $(1)$ is $O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, so squeezing gives that the wanted limit is indeed $\color{red}{\large\frac{1}{4}}$, since $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n^4}{(n^2+1)^2}=1$.

---

An alternative approach is given by the combinatorial identity:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{M+k}{M}=\binom{M+N+1}{M+1}. \tag{3}$$
For instance,
$$ 6\binom{n+1}{3}\leq n^3 \leq 6\binom{n+2}{3},\tag{4} $$
hence:
$$ 6\binom{N+2}{4} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} n^3 \leq 6\binom{N+3}{4}\tag{5} $$
If we multiply both sides of $(5)$ by $\frac{1}{(N^2+1)^2}$ and take the limit as $N\to +\infty$ we recover the previous result, always by squeezing.

Comment: Thanks Sir, but I'd never be able to use these methods in an examination situation, simply because they are completely unfamiliar to me and would not strike me. 
If it would be possible, could you please show me how I might correct the bounds I had taken in my method? Thanks!

Comment: @BarryCipra: well, yes, but I thought the linked theorem would be useful for the OP in other circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\int_{0}^nx^3 dx<\sum_{i=1}^ni^3<n^3+\int_0^nx^3dx$$

$$\frac{1}{4}n^4<\sum_{i=1}^ni^3<n^3+\frac{1}{4}n^4$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\frac{n^4}{(n^2+1)^2}<\frac{\sum_{i=1}^ni^3}{(n^2+1)^2}<\frac{1}{4}\frac{4n^3+n^4}{(n^2+1)^2}$$

Comment: This one comes from integral test for convergence ! +1